# Sequelize query nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I need to filter the "incomers" based on age, but in the table I only have the date of birth. I need people between the minimum and maximum age, how can I do it?

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    let parameters = JSON.parse(req.body.parameters);
    parameters.states = parameters.states.split();
    parameters.species = parameters.species.split();

    model.person.findAll({
        where: {
            uf: parameters.states,
            species: parameters.species,
            dateBirth: BETWEEN PARAMETERS.MINAGE AND PARAMETERS.MAXAGE
        }
    })
        .then(person => res.json({
            error: false,
            data: person
        }))
        .catch(error => res.json({
            error: true,
            data: [],
            error: error
        }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `between` operator:

```
model.person.findAll({
    where: {
        uf: parameters.states,
        species: parameters.species,
        dateBirth: {
          [Op.between]: ['2000-01-01', '2020-01-01'],
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like :

```
var startAge = 18;
var endAge = 20;

var today = moment();
var startDate = today.subtract('years', startAge);
var endDate = today.subtract('years', endAge);

model.person.findAll({
    where: {
        uf: parameters.states,
        species: parameters.species,
        dateBirth: : {
            $between: [startDate, endDate]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: but the parameters are ages
startAge: 18,
endAge: 20,
And date of birth is a date like this: "YYYY / MM / DD"

Comment: means you need to be born before 18 and 20 years back , right , so start date would be 1/1/1998 and end date would be 31/12/2000 , :) @FilippeOliveiraDaSilvaRodr

Comment: @FilippeOliveiraDaSilvaRodr , please check updated answer , I have showed by the use of moment js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Raw queries in your where something like -

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var now = '2010-01-01';//Current Date

model.person.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.literal('( (ud IN ('+parameters.states+')) AND (species IN ('+parameters.species+')) AND ((DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(dob,'+now+')), "%Y")+0) BETWEEN '+minDate+' AND '+maxDate+')  )')
})
```